# Core Animation backing view covers up other views unexpectedly

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation

I have a Mac App which has a window and I added a custom view to the window.  I added three buttons into the custom view via xcode drop/drag.  I then turned on the capability of using Core Animation to do a backing view. I added code to, in response to a 'test' button touch outside of the view, programmatically set the default color of the main CALayer to something and then added some subviews which were colored rectangles (as a test).  This all worked just fine.

My problem is, contrary to my expectations, the last colored rectangle partially covers up part of one of the buttons which I had originally put into the custom view.  Since this was a sublayer on a the layer associated with the background view, I had assumed that it would never block the buttons, no matter what went in there.  I called the subviews method to see if indeed the buttons were subviews of the main custom view and all are listed in the resulting NSArray.

What do I need to do to make the buttons come back on top again?  I have access to the NSButton and NSButtonCell objects both.

Here is the method that fires off when the 'test' button is pressed:

```
(IBAction)PushButtonTest:(id)sender {

NSRect localNSRectWorkArea;
NSRect localNSRectButton01;
NSRect localNSRectButton02;
NSRect localNSRectButton03;
NSArray *subviewarray;

CALayer *localCALayer;
CALayer *localsub01CALayer;

localNSRectWorkArea = [WorkAreaView bounds];

localNSRectButton01 = [Button01 frame];
localNSRectButton02 = [Button02 frame];
localNSRectButton03 = [Button03 frame];

localCALayer = [WorkAreaView layer];
CGColorRef color = CGColorCreateGenericRGB( 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 );
localCALayer.backgroundColor = color;
localCALayer.opacity = 1.0;

localsub01CALayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
localsub01CALayer.opacity = 0.5;
CGColorRef color1 = CGColorCreateGenericRGB( 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 );
localsub01CALayer.backgroundColor = color1;
float x1 = (localNSRectButton02.origin.x - localNSRectButton01.origin.x);
float y1 = (localNSRectButton02.origin.y - localNSRectButton01.origin.y);
localsub01CALayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, x1, y1);
float x3 = ((localNSRectButton02.origin.x + localNSRectButton01.origin.x)/2.0) + (localNSRectButton01.size.width/2.0);
float y3 = ((localNSRectButton02.origin.y + localNSRectButton01.origin.y)/2.0) + (localNSRectButton01.size.height/2.0);
localsub01CALayer.position = CGPointMake(x3, y3);

[localCALayer addSublayer:localsub01CALayer];

subviewarray = [WorkAreaView subviews];

[localCALayer displayIfNeeded];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an assignment localsub01CALayer.anchorpointZ = 0.5 (negative numbers are toward the viewer, positive numbers are away from the viewer, zero is on the plane of the display) and that took care of it.